# centos 7 nginx not accepting requests from outside networks

Tags: firewall, http, remote-access, nginx, centos-7

I'v configured a Nginx server on centos 7 and it works properly from the browser on the server. but when I try from any remote clients it says that it can not connect. I'v tried to add http to firewalld services.

```
    sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=80/tcp --permanent
```

and the result is :

```
 target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens192
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh http https
  ports: 80/tcp 443/tcp 8000/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

but when from another node i try:

```
sudo  nmap -sT  {ip address}
```

I got:

```
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp  open   ssh
443/tcp closed https
```

also if helpful, result of

```
sudo netstat -tulpn 

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17859/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1263/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12372/postgres      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1766/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      17859/nginx: master 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1263/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      12372/postgres      
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1766/master         
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           867/chronyd         
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                867/chronyd
```

also

```
sudo ufw status verbose

Status: inactive
```

and

```
sestatus

SELinux status:                 disabled
```

and also

```
sudo iptables -L -vn

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  674 64842 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 123K   21M INPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 123K   21M INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 123K   21M INPUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
 123K   21M REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
```

can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Did you reload firewall rules after adding port(s)?
What you see when you run `iptables -L -vn`?

Comment: @mariaczi yes I did. I did an edit then you can see the result of {iptables -L -vn} at the end of the post

Comment: Hmm. Where is the rest rules from you firewall? In INPUT table we can see that traffic to port 443 is accepted, but maybe in other tables: INPUT_direct, INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE, INPUT_ZONES you have something that not allow for input to port 80.

Comment: Please explain this sentence "when I try from any remote clients it says that it can not connect" - what do you mean? This server is connected to the internet with public IP or you try to connect to it from other computer in the same network?

Comment: @mariaczi thank you for your fast reply. Indeed I'm not experienced with the firewall. can you help me how to fix the issues you mentioned? the server is in a local LAN and I am trying to connect it from a client in the same LAN.

Comment: OK, so show the rest rules: `iptables -L INPUT_direct -vn`, `iptables -L INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE -vn`, `iptables -L INPUT_ZONES -vn`
And the best way to check if you will be able co connect to your nginx could be to disable/stop firewall and check if you got nginix welcome page. If yes, this will be means that the problem is in incorrect firewall configuration, not nginx configuration.